Pass Bearer Authorization header Nginx Proxy
I've a Docker container with Nginx server that acts as reverse proxy. The problem is that when the client calls to the server passing a authorization token in header, this token is not pass to the final endpoint and then the server give me a 401 error... My configuration file (default.conf) right now is:
server {
        listen       80;
        listen  [::]:80;
        server_name  localhost;

        if ($request_method = GET){
                return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        if ($request_method = POST){
                return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name _;

        http2 on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate-key.key;

        location /login/ {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.100.5:46000/login/;
        }

        location /dws/ {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.100.5:46001/dws/;
                proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        access_log /etc/nginx/log/https/access_register.log;
        error_log /etc/nginx/log/https/error_register.log;
}


My Nginx version is 1.25.5...
Any idea about what is it wrong? Or maybe something lack?
Thanks in advance!
I expect to figure out where it's the problem or what lacks
